# Make a loop in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Hello I want to know how to make a loop so that my js is through an id because I have an email id for 2 fields for 2 different forms
I would then be able to choose when I click on the id of my form right that displays the error only on the right form and vice versa

> My code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input#id_st-courriel").focusout(checkEmailField);
    });

    function checkEmailField() {    
        $fieldValue = $("input#id_st-courriel").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/checkEmailField',
            data: ({
                value: $fieldValue
            }),
            type: 'GET',
            success: function($data, $textStatus, $XMLHttpRequest) {
                if ($data != '') {
                    $("input#id_st-courriel").parent().prev('errorlist').remove();
                    $("input#id_st-courriel").parent().before($data);
                }
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

I have an id : id_st-courriel
and an other id for my second formulaire : id_em-courriel

For the moment I're the error display on my first form with the id: id_st-courriel

> Edit :

I have a second problem [image: error screnn shot]

> My views.py

```
def ajax_check_email_field(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    HTML_to_return = ''
    if 'value' in request.GET:
        field = forms.EmailField()
        try:
            field.clean(request.GET['value'])
        except exceptions.ValidationError as ve:
            HTML_to_return = '<ul class="errorList">'
            for message in ve.messages:
                HTML_to_return += '<li>' + message + '</li>'
            HTML_to_return += '</ul>'
    return HttpResponse(HTML_to_return)
```

Comment: what error you are getting? Can you tried html also?

Comment: I have no error for the moment just the function that normally can not display an error and already show that I can not make a loop to execute his will according to the id that I pass him values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make some minor changes to do it like

1. Update the selector to select both the fields - either use a class selector after add a common class to both the fields or use multiple selector syntax to select both the elements using their id
2. In the event handler dynamically select the current element by using `this` reference - in the event handler `this` will refer to the input element which triggered the event

So

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#id_st-courriel, #id_em-courriel").focusout(checkEmailField); //you can simplify the selector if you can add a common class to both these fields and then use the class selector to add the event handler
});

function checkEmailField() {
  var $fileld = $(this);
  var $fieldValue = $fileld.val();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/checkEmailField',
    data: ({
      value: $fieldValue
    }),
    type: 'GET',
    success: function($data, $textStatus, $XMLHttpRequest) {
      $fileld.parent().prev('.errorlist').remove();//may be .errorlist if it is a class
      if ($data != '') {
        $fileld.parent().before($data);
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much ! And anyone know why it shows all the time the same error if I leave the email field?
I would like to repeat that it stops if it is already the same error

Comment: What is errorlist if it is a class then you need  ('.errorlist'). remove()

Comment: Also that entire statement should be out of the if statement

Comment: @JérémyLegendre yes so `.prev('.errorlist').remove();`

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>

//You can select the list items and iterate across them:


$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass `$(this)` to you function `checkEmailField` to refer to the current focused out field, try :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input#id_st-courriel, input#id_em-courriel").focusout(function(){
        checkEmailField($(this));
  });
});

function checkEmailField(_this) {    
  $fieldValue = _this.val();

  $.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/checkEmailField',
    data: ({
      value: $fieldValue
    }),
    type: 'GET',
    success: function($data, $textStatus, $XMLHttpRequest) {
      if ($data != '') {
          $(_this).parent().prev('errorlist').remove();
          $(_this).parent().before($data);
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Hope this helps.